# Wordpress Single Post image gallery as slider

Tags: images

I would like to make image sliders within my single posts, but the following way:

I want the attached gallery to show as an image slider, I suppose with javascript slider.

I have no idea how to achieve that, I tried just inserting splidejs in my single-post template, did not work.

Could someone help me to achieve it?

The basic idea is whatever images I insert as a gallery to a single post through the wp-admin ui, it would appear as slider within the post.

Comment: You should load the script via an [enqueue-scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) hook, e.g. from your theme's functions.php, and you'll then need to do the [Writing HTML section of 'Getting Started'](https://splidejs.com/getting-started/) in your single-post template.

Comment: That part is totally ok, loading any script with functions.php hook, but the problem is that altough this javascript uses ul and li divs, when I load it even with the most simple way (new Splide( '#splide' ).mount(); ), it says "Splide is not defined".

Altough, if I include it in the single-post template php with script-source, it gives this error:
Track or list was not found.